# How to make a quick analysis-like floating menu in VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I want to know anybody knows if there is in VSTO a control or a way to create a popup like Quick Analysis that appears at the right-bottom of a given range:

[image: Quick Analysis Popup Menu]

I'm creating an Excel plugin in VS2013 with C#, the plugin should be compatible on Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013. If such control can only be created on the latest version of Excel (2013) that may not be an option for deploy. I´ve already created a traditional Windows form to do this, but I'll like to know if there are better ways to show new controls to the user, closer to where the action is occurring. Thanks!